# ChartJS How to provide an array of objects as a dataset?

Tags: chart.js

I've got a dataset that looks like so;

```
[
  "transactions": [
    {
      "month": "Dec",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "333a32c6-eaf0-3f11-8a2b-963282fb700c",
          "amount": "776",
          "created_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        },
        {
          "id": "36688452-92f2-3ae7-911a-9543fe29cae6",
          "amount": "1798",
          "created_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        },
        {
          "id": "67856ceb-1eb5-369b-b3c1-7bd92c037c70",
          "amount": "9507",
          "created_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        },
        {
          "id": "7e9465be-0151-3828-b429-2b7c4db2aa5e",
          "amount": "944",
          "created_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        },
        {
          "id": "dd5019b5-690b-33e0-a633-de6162cd687a",
          "amount": "5327",
          "created_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        },
        {
          "id": "eb5f1473-e871-357d-be3c-af2dc00ff22d",
          "amount": "4638",
          "created_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "month": "Mar",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "5929f7ad-7ad5-35dc-9935-c06bc0283f20",
          "amount": "5251",
          "created_at": "2019-03-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "month": "Nov",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "8c36b5dd-2b15-3024-83f4-551df33d9fcc",
          "amount": "3643",
          "created_at": "2019-11-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        },
        {
          "id": "abcd4af5-7a7e-3a9b-8c02-f251f6724062",
          "amount": "2622",
          "created_at": "2019-11-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "month": "Oct",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "925b5efb-7933-396e-96ab-9473a93009ff",
          "amount": "8674",
          "created_at": "2019-10-04 10:57:50",
          "updated_at": "2019-12-04 10:57:50"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Basically I want to show a chart with all the months of the year, and if they aren't present in the transactions array, it returns just 0 for that month on the chart.

How would I go about parsing this object and making sure it all matches up with my labels on my chart? All examples in the documentation use really basic integer's as the dataset and there are no examples I could find of using an object!

Comment: Instead of the from you so called basic integers from the doc examples you just create data objects and push these into the data parts of your chart in JavaScript.

Comment: @Phanti Right but how can I tell chartjs what object property to show on the chart? They don't exactly make that very clear in the docs from my reading.